# Smalltalk html select: what to put in value?

Tags: html, select, callback, smalltalk, seaside

i hope somebody can help me because i think it is probably a trivial problem.

Here is my code extract:

```
renderNewForm: html

    1 to: self anzahlFelder
        do: 
            [:i |
            (html textInput)
                value: (self nameAn: i);
                callback: [:aString | namen at: i put: aString trimBoth].
            (html select)
                list: #(1 2 3);"ToDo: namen als auswahl"
                value:();
                callback:[:nr| self strategien at: i put: nr].
                html break]
```

I want that the chosen number from the list (example 1, 2 or 3) is put into my OrderedCollection strategien. I'm also not sure what to put in value therefor or if I even need it.

Comment: looks good to me... Are you running Seaside 2 or 3? That makes a big difference.

Comment: have you tried just putting `#(1 2 3)` for value?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your exact problem please?
I remember being frustrated, because I did not realize that *the callback was only executed when placed into a form and the form was submitted*. Here I changed the Seaside 3.1 `WACounter` example for you to work with `WASelectTag`. Just change the `#renderContentOn:` method in `WACounter` like this:

```
renderContentOn: html

html heading: count.
html form:[
    html select
        list: #(#Increase #Decrease);
        callback: [ :value | (value = #Increase) ifTrue: [self increase] ifFalse: [self decrease] ].
    html submitButton with: 'And Action!' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a strategy class

```
Object subclass: #Strategy
   instanceVariableNames: 'nr title'
   classVariableNames: ''
   category: 'Demo-Seaside-Model'
```

with the corresponding accessors,

```
Strategy>>nr
    ^nr

Strategy>>nr: aNr
    nr := aNr

Strategy>>title
    ^title ifNil: ['']

Strategy>>title: aTitle
    title := aTitle
```

and a method returning a formatted string

```
Strategy>>selectString
    ^(nr asString), ' - ',title asString
```

you can have a WAComponent subclass do

```
renderChooseStrategyOn: canvas
    canvas select
        list: self allStrategies;
        on: #selectedStrategy of: self;
        labels: [ :each | each selectString].
```

It then needs a selectedStrategy instance variable+accessors, and a method allStrategies.